# Itarate password combinations to find key for string

Tags: python, encryption

I´m having problems to brute force the key for a string encrypted with RC4/ARC4.

This is the encrypted string:
`E7Ev08_MEojYBixHRKTKQnRSC4hkriZ7XPsy3p4xAHUPj41Dlzu9`

And the string is also hashed with base64, so complete encoded string is:
`RTdFdjA4X01Fb2pZQml4SFJLVEtRblJTQzRoa3JpWjdYUHN5M3A0eEFIVVBqNDFEbHp1OQ==`

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import threading
import sys
import time
import re
import itertools
from itertools import product
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
import base64


def special_match(strg):
  try:
    strg.decode('utf-8')
  except UnicodeDecodeError:
    pass
  else:
    print('\nkey found at %s, key: %s' % (time.ctime(), rc4_key))
    try:
            f=open('key.txt','ab')
            f.write('Key (%s): %s\n' % (time.ctime(), rc4_key))
            f.write('Decrypted string: ' + strg + '\n')
            f.close()
    except Exception as e:
            print('ERROR WRITING KEY TO FILE: ' + str(e))

chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
end_chars = chars[::-1][0:7]

encoded_string = 'RTdFdjA4X01Fb2pZQml4SFJLVEtRblJTQzRoa3JpWjdYUHN5M3A0eEFIVVBqNDFEbHp1OQ=='


spinner = itertools.cycle(['-', '/', '|', '\\'])

while 1:
      try:
        # Iteration processess of possibel keys
        for length in range(7,8): # only do length of 7
            for attempt in itertools.permutations(chars, length):
                rc4_key = ''.join(attempt) # This key is unknown, we are looking for it..
                Ckey = ARC4.new(rc4_key)
                decoded = Ckey.decrypt(encoded_string.decode('base64'))
                special_match(decoded)

                sys.stdout.write(spinner.next())  # write the next character
                sys.stdout.flush()                # flush stdout buffer (actual character display)
                sys.stdout.write('\b')            # erase the last written char

                # Exit the script when we have done all password-combination-iterations
                if (rc4_key == end_chars):
                  print('iteration of combinations done! No key found.. :(\n' + time.ctime())
                  exit()

      except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nKeybord interrupt, exiting gracefully anyway on %s at %s' % (rc4_key, time.ctime()))
        sys.exit()
```

I´m using http://crypo.bz.ms/secure-rc4-online to encrypt the string and https://www.base64encode.org to encode it with UTF-8.

## Question

Why doesn't my script work to find the key?

(Im not receiving any error message, it is more of a general question if I have missed something in my code, or approach of the problem.)

plaintext: `This is something that I have encrypted`, key: `ABCFMSG`

Comment: Inconsistent indentation can cause issues.

Comment: Does the decription work if provided with  the right key?

Comment: Also there are 8 billion possible keys, it could take a long, long time

Comment: @JeD But the key is `ABCFMSG` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems that crypo.bz uses a realy weird system. Basically they have a really weird encoding which causes discrepancies if you simply use their characters.

For example encoding 'a' with key 'A' should produce a character with value 163.

In hex A3. In crypo.bz we get 'oc' instead.

So you have two possibilities. Either do some ciphertext analysis or use another site.  I recommend this one as they tell you in what they encode the result:

http://www.fyneworks.com/encryption/RC4-Encryption/index.asp

Take the hex and convert it to string, the you should be able to decipher it

Your code seems to be working by the way ;)

Tell me if you have additional questions

EDIT: did some additional analysis, and it is really, really weird.
in crypo.bz IF the algorithm is correct 163 is oc

160 is nc

but 161 is mc ??

If anyone figures this out please tell me!

EDITEDIT:

here is the encrypted, but not encoded string '#ÔèïH§¢6pbpÊ]õªœIôŒ>Yœ5îfäGuæxÖa…ë6°'

Your program takes like half a second to find the key ;)

[image]